# How to check if a class in already exists in parse and create programatically

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am developing and android app where i want to programatically create new class in parse platform only if the same class name doesnt exist.

I have tried to go through dofferent documentations but havent found any that can help me.

All i am after is when a user tries to create a class it will first check if there is any class with the same name and if there is not then it will create a class programatically. 
I know how to create an ParseObject but not sure how to do query for classes.

Comment: I doubt those generated class are compiled so it is just a file at this point. Chech if it exist `Paths.get("my/java/class.java").toFile().exists`

Comment: Parse Class is a complete different animal. There is no Java Class created in the application. The whole schema is stored inside the database.

Answer (score 0):

Parse Server requires sending Master Key for manipulating (reading and updating) the application's schema. Having your master key in your Android application would be a security flaw since a hacker could access it and then erase your whole database. By this reason, Parse does not allow schema manipulation from Android applications. You have two options though.

## Just Send a First Object

When you send a first object, by design, Parse Server already behaves like you want, a schemaless database. It means that you don't need to create your class beforehand. Just send the data and Parse Server will not only store it, but also create a new class if needed.

## Using Cloud Code

You can write a cloud code function to check the class existence and then create it. You can call this cloud code function from your Android application.

The cloud code would be something like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('ensureClass', async () => {
  const mySchema = new Parse.Schema('MyClass');
  try {
    mySchema.get({ useMasterKey: true });
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.message === 'Schema not found.') {
      mySchema
        .addString('stringField')
        .addNumber('numberField')
        .addBoolean('booleanField')
        .addDate('dateField');
      await mySchema.save({ useMasterKey: true });
    } else {
      throw e;
    }
  }
});
```

Ref: https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#schema

Then you could use the following code to call the function from the Android application:

```
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("ensureClass", params, new FunctionCallback<Float>() {
   void done(Object result, ParseException e) {
       if (e == null) {
          // success
       }
   }
});
```

Ref: https://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#cloud-functions

Comment: Thanks for your help Davi. I think thats what i was looking for. Havent tried yet but seems like that the right direction :)

Comment: This doesnt work for me, i get class not found